# Sharepoint 2013 - EditForm, people picker new value not saving

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have used below code to Add value in people picker. The code works fine in NewForm.aspx. But when I edit the people picker in EditForm.aspx it doesnt take the new value. It saves the old value only.

```
function SetNewPeoplePicker(controlName, Username) {
var ppDiv = jQuery("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");      
var ppEditor = ppDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']"); 
var spPP = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[ppDiv[0].id];          
ppEditor.val(Username);                 // Set the value
spPP.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);                 // Resolve the User if (!spPP.HasInputError) 
{
        var userKeys = spPP.GetAllUserInfo();
        var myUser = userKeys[0];
        Manager = myUser.AutoFillDisplayText;
}
spPP.SetEnabledState(false);
jQuery('a.sp-peoplepicker-delImage').hide();
```

}

I read that we have to change  webpart properties to "Server Rendering". But the whole UI changes and my code written in JS for other field fails.

Can anyone please provide a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using SharePoint 2013 I would recommend you to consider the following approach. In SharePoint 2013 was introduced a so called `Client Rendering Mode (CSR)` which is intended for rendering of List Views and Forms using HTML and JavaScript and which is a *default rendering mode*.

### How to initialize User field in New/Edit forms using CSR

Below example demonstrates how to initialize User field (`AssignedTo` field in *Tasks* List) in *New* & *Edit* forms:

Template code:

```
(function () {
    var ctx = {};
    ctx.Templates = {};
    ctx.Templates.Fields = {
        'AssignedTo': {
            'NewForm': renderPeoplePickerWithDefaultValue,
            'EditForm': renderPeoplePickerWithDefaultValue
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
})();

function renderPeoplePickerWithDefaultValue(ctx) {
     //1.set user field value
     var loginName = String.format('i:0#.f|membership|{0}',_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName);  //set to current user login name
     var displayName = $('div#SuiteNavUserName').text();   //set to current user display name 
     var userEntry = createUserEntity(loginName,displayName);
     ctx.CurrentFieldValue = [];   //Note: it is assumed the user field is a multi-valued field (!)
     ctx.CurrentFieldValue.push(userEntry);
     //2.render default People Picker  
     return SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate(ctx); 
}

function createUserEntity(loginName,displayName)
{
   return {
      Description: loginName,
      DisplayText: displayName,
      EntityGroupName: "",
      EntityType: "",
      HierarchyIdentifier: null,
      IsResolved: true,
      Key: loginName,
      MultipleMatches: [],
      ProviderDisplayName: "",
      ProviderName: ""
   };
}
```

> P.S.: in the specified example `AssignedTo` field is set to current
>   user, in order to specify another user, modify `loginName` and
>   `displayName` parameters.
>
> P.P.S. The example has been tested in SharePoint Online

### How to apply the changes

There are at least two options how to apply the changes:

1. Using [JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx)
2. Place JavaScript template on page via `Script Editor`/`Content Editor`
   web parts

Here is how to apply the changes using the **second option**:

1. Switch the page (`NewForm.aspx`) into edit mode
2. Add `Script Editor` webpart right below the list view web part.
3. Put the specified code by wrapping it using `script` tag code into the Script Editor, for example: `<script type="text/javascript">{Template JS code goes here}</script>`
4. Save the page

### Results

[image]

### References

- [INTRODUCTION TO CLIENT-SIDE RENDERING IN SHAREPOINT 2013](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)